# Haskell date parsing and formatting

Tags: haskell, formatting, date

I've been working with Haskell's Date.Time modules to parse a date like `12-4-1999` or `1-31-1999`.  I tried:

```
parseDay :: String -> Day
parseDay s = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%m%d%Y" s
```

And I think it wants my months and days to have exactly two digits instead of 1 or 2...

What's the proper way to do this?

Also, I'd like to print out my Day in this format: `12/4/1999` what's the Haskell way to?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: don't you need dashes between the %m, %d, and %Y anyway?

Comment: @AlexBaranosky you may want to consider accepting a different answer to this question :)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Here is some old code that contains two types of homemade dates, dates with just YMD, no time or timezones, etc.

It shows how to  parse strings into dates using `readDec`.  See the `parseDate` function.  With `readDec`, *read* the number, it doesn't matter about leading spaces(because of `filter`) or leading zeros,and the parse stops at the first non-digit.  Then used `tail` (to skip the non digit) to get to the next numerical field of the date.

It shows several ways of formatting for output, but the most flexible way is to use `Text.printf`. See `instance Show LtDate`. With *printf*, anything is possible!

```
import Char
import Numeric
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.Clock
import Text.Printf
-- ================================================================
--                        LtDate
-- ================================================================
type Date=(Int,Int,Int)
data LtDate = LtDate 
  { ltYear :: Int,
    ltMonth:: Int,
    ltDay  :: Int
  } 
instance Show LtDate 
  where show d = printf "%4d-%02d-%02d" (ltYear d) (ltMonth d) (ltDay d)

toLtDate :: Date -> LtDate
toLtDate (y,m,d)= LtDate y m d

-- =============================================================
--                         Date
-- =============================================================
-- | Parse a String mm/dd/yy into tuple (y,m,d)
-- accepted formats
--
-- @
-- 12\/01\/2004
-- 12\/ 1\' 4
-- 12-01-99
-- @
parseDate :: String -> Date
parseDate s = (y,m,d)
    where [(m,rest) ] = readDec (filter (not . isSpace) s)
          [(d,rest1)] = readDec (tail rest)
          [(y, _)   ] = parseDate' rest1

-- | parse the various year formats used by Quicken dates
parseDate':: String -> [(Int,String)]
parseDate' (y:ys) =
  let [(iy,rest)] = readDec ys
      year=case y of '\''      -> iy + 2000
                     _  ->
                       if iy < 1900 then  iy + 1900 else iy
   in [(year,rest)]

-- | Note some functions sort by this format
-- | So be careful when changing it.
showDate::(Int, Int, Int) -> String
showDate (y,m,d)= yy ++ '-':mm ++ '-':dd
    where dd=zpad (show d)
          mm = zpad (show m)
          yy = show y
          zpad ds@(_:ds')
           | ds'==[] = '0':ds
           | otherwise = ds


-- | from LtDate to Date
fromLtDate :: LtDate -> Date
fromLtDate  lt = (ltYear lt, ltMonth lt, ltDay lt)
```

Once you have (Y,M,D), it's easy to convert to a Haskell library type for data manipulations.  Once you are done with the HS libraries, `Text.printf` can be used to format a date for display.

Comment: that seems ridiculously complicated!  There must be a simpler way, god help me

Comment: Please take a closer look, the code was an example and is not all necessary: To parse the date`parseDate` requires only 4 lines; call `readDec` 3 times.  To show a date use Text.printf` once.  Load the file and run it on your date to see that it works, then look at those `parseDat`e and `printf`. This parseDate ignores spaces and doesn't care about the seperator '-', or '/' in the dates.  It changes '55 to 1955, etc.  It is 10 lines(includes `parseDate'`)`ShowDate`, and `fromLtDate` and the `data` statements are not needed. Neither are Clock and Calender includes.

Comment: Delete everything except `parseDate` and `parseDate'` it will make it look simpler. Keep the includes for `Data.Char` and `Numeric` The year parser, `parseDate'` can be replaced with another call to `readDec`.

Answer (score 68):

You can use the functions in `Data.Time.Format` to read in the dates.  I've included a trivial program below that reads in a date in one format and writes that date back out in two different formats. To read in single-digit months or days, place a single hyphen (-) between the % and format specifier. In other words to parse dates formatted like 9-9-2012 then include a single hyphen between the % and the format characters. So to parse "9-9-2012" you would need the format string "%-d-%-m-%Y".

Note: This answer is getting a bit long-in-the-tooth given the rate at which Haskell packages evolve. It might be time to look for a better solution. I'm no longer writing Haskell so it would be nice if someone else created another answer since this question ranks highly in Google results.

**As of July 2017**, you are encouraged to use parseTimeOrError. The code becomes:

```
import Data.Time

main =
  do
    let dateString = "26 Jan 2012 10:54 AM"
    let timeFromString = parseTimeOrError True defaultTimeLocale "%d %b %Y %l:%M %p" dateString :: UTCTime
    -- Format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM
    print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" timeFromString
    -- Format MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM AM/PM
    print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p" timeFromString

    -- now for a string with single digit months and days:
    let dateString = "9-8-2012 10:54 AM"
    let timeFromString = parseTimeOrError True defaultTimeLocale "%-d-%-m-%Y %l:%M %p" dateString :: UTCTime
    -- Format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM
    print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" timeFromString
```

The versions from the .cabal file:
build-depends:       base >=4.9 && <4.10, time >= 1.6.0.1

**As of August, 2014**, the locale was best obtained from the `System.Locale` package rather than the Haskell 1998 `Locale` package. With that in mind, the sample code from above now reads:

```
import System.Locale
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Format

main =
  do
    let dateString = "26 Jan 2012 10:54 AM"
    let timeFromString = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%d %b %Y %l:%M %p" dateString :: UTCTime
    -- Format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM
    print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" timeFromString
    -- Format MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM AM/PM
    print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p" timeFromString

    -- now for a string with single digit months and days:
    let dateString = "9-8-2012 10:54 AM"
    let timeFromString = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%-d-%-m-%Y %l:%M %p" dateString :: UTCTime
    -- Format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM
    print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" timeFromString
```

output now looks like this:

```
"2012/01/26 10:54"
"01/26/2012 10:54 AM"
"2012/08/09 10:54"
```

**Original, January 2012** answer:

```
import Locale
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Format

main =
  do
    let dateString = "26 Jan 2012 10:54 AM"
    let timeFromString = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%d %b %Y %l:%M %p" dateString :: UTCTime
    -- Format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM
    print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" timeFromString
    -- Format MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM AM/PM
    print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p" timeFromString
```

The output looks like this:

```
"2012/01/26 10:54"
"01/26/2012 10:54 AM"
```

`Data.Time.Format` is available from the `time` package. If you need to parse single-digit months or days, in other words dates like 9-9-2012 then include a single hyphen between the % and the format characters. So to parse "9-9-2012" you would need the format string "%-d-%-m-%Y".

Comment: For the lazy, this is in the 'time' package.

Comment: I get `Ambiguous occurrence ‘defaultTimeLocale’` which is it, `Data.Time.defaultTimeLocale` or `System.Locale.defaultTimeLocale`?

Comment: See my edits. This answer is starting to show its age, but it worked on OS X with cabal-install 1.24.0.2 and ghc 8.0.2.

Comment: I think in cases like these it would be better to post another answer with the updated code, possibly even update the original answer and post a new answer with the 'old' answer. Right now the oldest 'solution' appears on top of the question.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: I see your point. I re-ordered the sections so the most recent one is first. Feel free to edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 14):

Using %-d and %-m instead of %d and %m means single digit day/month is OK, i.e.

```
parseDay :: String -> Day
parseDay s = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%-m%-d%Y" s
```

This may be what sclv meant, but his comment was a little too cryptic for me.

Comment: +1 for the `-` flag for indicating the possible single digit month/day. I was pulling my hair out over this and about to turn to regexes!

Comment: It's documented here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html

Answer (score 7):

Since recently, I'll advice to use [strptime](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strptime) package for all your date/time parsing needs.