# Parse an ISO formatted date string into its components

Tags: date, parsing, datetime, haskell

I am new to haskell and wanted to approach learngin by attempting bits of a real world application.  One of the components is being able to parse dates in ISO formatted strings into it's components.  [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174372/haskell-date-parsing-and-formatting) helped me get started, but it isn't enough and I am quite confused.

I have the following code:

```
import System.Locale
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Format

data IsoDate  = IsoDate {
    year :: Int
    , month :: Int
    , day :: Int
} deriving (Show)

parseIsoDate :: String -> IsoDate
parseIsoDate dateString = 
    IsoDate year month day
    where 
        timeFromString = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y %m %d" dateString :: UTCTime
        year = 2013
        month = 10
        day = 31
```

Which is fine and dandy for Halloween 2013.  I have attmepted to rewrite year as:

```
year = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%y" timeFromString
```

which I knew would fail (can't construct my `IsoDate` type with a `String`). And then attempted to read the string into an Int.

```
year = read (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%y" timeFromString)
```

with the following response:

```
 parseIsoDate "2012-12-23"
 IsoDate {year = *** Exception: readsTime: bad input "2012-12-23"
```

There were a couple other attemps at getting this converted - but what I posted was the most rational attempt, o I am not going to post the other attempts.

I wanted to figure out how to work with my current code (as I am trying to learn the constructs), in addition (since date parsing is essential) I would like to know the better way (perhaps the most idiomatic) to handle this in Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the stuff you need to do is

```
parseIsoDate :: String -> Maybe IsoDate
```

because not every `String` you supply will be a valid date. Implementing it you already got most of the ingredients right, but I don't think yo uwant to parse a `UTCTime` but a `Day` which can be converted into your data-structure.

```
import Data.Time

data IsoDate = ...

parseIsoDate :: String -> Maybe IsoDate
parseIsoDate str = do julianDay <- parse str
                      let (y, m, d) = toGregorian julianDay
                      return $ IsoDate (fromIntegral y) m d

  where parse:: String -> Maybe Day
        parse = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%F"
```

now a bit explaining and advice:

1. I would change the datatype `IsoDate` to using `Integer` for years - as they are possibly big (at least bigger than `Int` - just look at the age of our universe). this is also the choice of the result of `toGregorian` which converts a `Day -> (Integer, Int, Int)`, if not you have to convert the `Integer` produced by it to an `Int` with the help of `fromIntegral` as you see in my example.
2. the syntax I use is called **do-syntax** for `Maybe`, which is a handy thing in the first line I extract a value inside the monad and **bind** it to a name - `julianDay`.
   Then I transform the value to a Gregorian Day.
   And then `return` it into the `Maybe` again. If the first step fails and produces a `Nothing`, i.e. the `String` is just gobbledygook, then none of the other operations are done and your program finishes without doing any work (that's the power of lazy evaluation).

### update

If you are using the `RecordWildCards` extension, and the fact that maybe is a `Functor` you can do the following

```
{-# LANGUAGE Record
module MyLib
import Data.Time

data IsoDate = IsoDate { year :: Integer
                       , month :: Int
                       , day :: Int}
              deriving (Show)

parseIsoDate :: String -> Maybe IsoDate
parseIsoDate str = do (year, month, day) <- toGregorian <$> parse str
                      return IsoDate{..}

  where parse:: String -> Maybe Day
        parse = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%F"
```

Comment: Cool,  I went with UtcTime because of the example I found started there. Day makes more sense (there is no time component to our data).  %F is nice (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#t:FormatTime).  I haven't got to the "do" syntax yet, although I have seen it.  Does it just enable syntatic sugar with Monads? (I will have to skip ahead),

Comment: Also - I agree on the Maybe  - Just (no pun intended) was focusing on getting the other syntax right.

Comment: "Do-syntax" is usually only used in the context of monads - but don't be afraid it's way less scary than you think it is. There is an extension in ghc called  `ApplicativeDo` which enables you to use this syntax in an `Applicative` context which is slightly more general but less powerful - and also not as scary as it sounds.

Comment: Thanks - I have been coding exclusively in JS over the past 4 years, so jumping back into static languages after a long layoff.  Prior I was coding in F# and have been working in a functional style in JS - but I feel like I need to learn Haskell (curiosity).  My pet project is building a DSL for my business domain, which would be a great fit for F#, and I think there are many similar constructs in Haskell.  Anyhow focusing getting the Abstract Syntax Tree up and running first, then parsing into it from a grammar will be the last bit

Comment: I think I may be missing something - I pasted your code and am getting the following error: "parse error on input `let'" - i think the spacing looks OK...

Comment: I removed the name shadowing - sorry I didn't try out the code, I modified it while typing it.

Comment: OK - I needed to update haskell to use parseTimeM (I installed about 12 months ago and hadn't ahd the opportuntiy to start learning until today) and was able to get your solution to work in its entirety.  I dont understand the spacing -- particualrly the "do"...  But it is working.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is one answer:

```
data IsoDate  = IsoDate {
    year :: Int
    , month :: Int
    , day :: Int
} deriving (Show)

parseIsoDate :: String -> IsoDate
parseIsoDate dateString = 
    IsoDate year month day
    where 
        timeFromString = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y %m %d" dateString :: UTCTime
        year = read (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%0Y" timeFromString) :: Int
        month = read (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%m" timeFromString) :: Int
        day = read (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%d" timeFromString) :: Int
```

Which refactors to:

```
data DatePart = Year | Month | Day deriving(Enum, Show)

datePart :: DatePart ->  UTCTime -> Int
datePart Year utcTime = read (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%0Y" utcTime)
datePart Month utcTime = read (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%m" utcTime)
datePart Day utcTime = read (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%d" utcTime)

parseIsoDate :: String -> IsoDate
parseIsoDate dateString = 
    IsoDate year month day
    where 
        timeFromString = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y %m %d" dateString :: UTCTime
        year = datePart Year timeFromString
        month = datePart Month timeFromString
        day = datePart Day timeFromString
```

in usage

```
 parseIsoDate "2012 12 02"
```

THat data isn't in ISO format, still working to get it to read "2012-12-01".  Also still looking for the preferred way of getting this to work within the language.

---

update  the dashes are trivial change "%Y %m %d" to "%Y-%m-%d"  I thought I had tried that eariler, but it must have been with other code in  error.