# Text friendly way of parsing text timestamps in Haskell

Tags: haskell, time

I have some timestamps (with additional text around them) I am parsing.  I understand I [can parse time strings generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174372/haskell-date-parsing-and-formatting) with Data.Time.

However, after I convert the datetime from a Text to a String with unpack, I don't understand how to parse this error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric,  OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Time.Parse
import Data.Text as T

myDate = "D2017/01/01" 

:t parseTimeOrError

ptime :: Text -> UTCTime 
ptime dt = parseTimeOrError True defaultTimeLocale "D%Y/%d/%M" (T.unpack dt) :: UTCTime
-- here the T.unpack is because the :t tells us parseTimeOrError takes a string
-- not a Text.

myUTC <- ptime myDate

print myUTC
```

I get

```
parseTimeOrError :: forall t. ParseTime t => Bool -> TimeLocale -> String -> String -> t
<interactive>:1:10: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’ with actual type ‘UTCTime’
    • In the first argument of ‘GHC.GHCi.ghciStepIO :: forall a. IO a -> IO a’, namely ‘(ptime myDate)’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: myUTC <- GHC.GHCi.ghciStepIO :: forall a. IO a -> IO a (ptime myDate)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is a little confusing ... it looks like parts of this are from a `.hs` file and other parts are from a `ghci` session. In any case, I think the problem is `myUTC <- ptime myDate`. You can only use the `<-` notation when you're in a `do` block, pulling a value out of a monad (in this case, the `ghci` prompt is an implicit `do` block in the `IO` monad). Instead try `let myUTC = ptime myDate`.

Comment: Thanks, it's been confusing to me, too.  I'm using an ihaskell notebook in jupyter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DarthFennec was right.  Replace

```
myUTC <- ptime myDate
```

With

```
myUTC = ptime myDate
```

I would not have understood that from the error above.  This is not related to Text or Data.Time.